# Strange behavior in update mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want update my Db.

My script is:

```
db.model( 'User', userSchema, usersCollection ).update(
    { _id: mongoose.mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID.fromString(obj_param._id) },
    { $set: {username: "peter"} },
    { upsert: false, multi: false }, function( err, nUpdated ){
        if( err ) {
            console.log(err)
        }else {
            console.log("OK");
        }
    })
```

This script works, but if i use

```
var obj = {username: "peter"}
```

and then

```
db.model( 'User', userSchema, usersCollection ).update(
    { _id: mongoose.mongo.BSONPure.ObjectID.fromString(obj_param._id) },
    { $set: obj },
    { upsert: false, multi: false }, function( err, nUpdated ){
        if( err ) {
            console.log(err)
        }else {
            console.log("OK");
        }
    })
```

i receive this error

```
[Error: Invalid atomic update value for $set. Expected an object, received string]
```

Comment: Impossible. Either something stringifies or something overwrites your `obj`. Show us more code.

Comment: `obj` must be a string and not the object you think it is.